# XNA Slow down Animation

Tags: c#, xna, sprite-sheet

I am making the character run but the animation is extremely quick as I am doing:

`_frameIndex++;`

`_frameIndex;` is the value which points to the image in the SpriteSheet. Does anyone know how I can use `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds` to slow the animation down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw that you've asked a couple of questions tonight concerning animation and spritesheets, so here's an example from Aaron Reed's "[Learning XNA 4.0](http://www.aaronreed.com/dnn/LearningXNA40.aspx)," from Chapter 3 under the "Adjusting the Animation Speed" heading.

First, create two class-level variables to track time between animation frames:

```
int timeSinceLastFrame = 0;
int millisecondsPerFrame = 50;
```

The first variable tracks time passed since the animation frame was changed, and the second is an arbitrary amount of time that you specify to wait before moving the frame index again. So making `millisecondsPerFrame` smaller will increase the animation speed, and making it larger will decrease the animation speed.

Now, in your update method, you can take advantage of `game.ElapsedGameTime` to check time passed since the last frame change, and change the frame when when that value greater than millisecondsPerFrame, you can do work:

```
timeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
if (timeSinceLastFrame > millisecondsPerFrame){
    timeSinceLastFrame -= millisecondsPerFrame;
    // Increment Current Frame here (See link for implementation)
}
```

This sort of solution is similar to what you've found works, except that you can take an extra step to specify *exactly how often you want the animation to update*, or even change that duration later on in your code if you like.  For example, if have some condition that would "speed up" the sprite (like a power-up) or likewise slow it down, you could do so by changing `millisecondsPerFrame`.

I removed the code that actually updates the current frame, since you should already have something that does that since you have a working animation.   If you'd like to see the example in-full, you can download it from the textbook's website.

Comment: Hi Anthony - Thank you very very much for this answer. The code doesn't make sense me to YET, I just need to read it a couple of times and hopefully it'll sink in. It sounds promising and once I fully understand, i'll put it in my code!

Comment: Anthony, why not just do `timeSinceLastFrame = 0;` instead of `timeSinceLastFrame -= millisecondsPerFrame;`?

Comment: Consistency, mostly, but either would work.  Reiterating Kevin's comment, be careful not to assume that the frame rate will never change.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "consistency" and why you prefer it over to reassigning it to 0? I'm just interested to know as your way might be much better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I debugged the code and noticed that the `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds` always equated to 33. So I did the following:

`milliSeconds += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
                    if (milliSeconds > 99)
                    {
                        _frameIndex++;
                        milliSeconds = 0;
                    }`

Which basically means that if this is the THIRD frame of the game, then make he _frameIndex go up. Reset the milliseconds to start over.

Comment: How I read your code is, " Only update the animation  once  every .099  secondsor slower,"  which makes a lot ofsense to me. I would be careful not to assume that the frame rate will never change,  though.  Different people's machines will perform differently,  and what other programs they're running at the same time can also make a difference.